# Getting Image w/ BitmapFactory

Tags: android, bitmapfactory

I'm not sure why this is not getting my image. This is my first time working with android apps with java so idk what to do.

```
public class Player {

private GameView view;

private Bitmap bmp;
public int x, y;

public Player(GameView view) {
    this.view = view;

}

public void tick() {

//This is my error here//
    bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher);

}

public void onDraw(Canvas c) {
    c.drawBitmap(bmp, x, y, null);
}

}
```

I'm getting an error when trying to set bmp equal to what I want it to be in my tick method for getResources(). I don't know why getResources() is wrong.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getResources()` is a method on `Context`. Your call to `getResources()` is not in a Java class that inherits from `Context`. You probably copied this code from some class that *does* inherit from `Context`, like `Activity`.

Your `onDraw()` method suggests that you are trying to create some custom `View`. If so, `Player` would need to inherit from `View`, and then you could use `getContext()` in order to retrieve a `Context` to use for `getResources()` (e.g., `getContext().getResources()`.